# undefined constant file for php future version

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a plugin in my wordpress site.But for one of the function i am getting this warning.this is the warning:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant file_put_contents - assumed
>   'file_put_contents' (this will throw an Error in a future version of
>   PHP)

This is the function where i am getting this warning.It's for the second line  i am getting the warning:

```
function qrs_create_css_file ($update) {
    if (function_exists(file_put_contents)) {
        $css_dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/quick-range-custom.css' ;
        $filename = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
        if (is_writable($filename) && (!file_exists($css_dir) || !empty($update))) {
            $data = qrs_generate_css();
            file_put_contents($css_dir, $data, LOCK_EX);
            }
        }
    else add_action('wp_head', 'qrs_head_css');
    }
```

How can i resolve this warning?

Comment: Your hosting provider has disabled the function `file_put_contents`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
    if (function_exists('file_put_contents')) {
```

You are not using quotation around `file_put_contents` which led the system to assume that it is a constant.